# Lua program. Input an integer number ''n'' and output the sum: 1+2^2+3^2+...+n^2. Use input validation for n to be positive

Tags: int

guys. I'm new here, and i'm also new in programming in Lua.
I wrote this code, but i'm stuck. Maybe the whole code is wrong.
I need help for this program. 
The program must ask the user to input a number "n". And "n" must be positive.
This is the task, that i need to implement 1+2^2+3^2+...+n^2
Then the program  must make the sumation and show the result. 
Sorry for my English.
Here's my code:

```
    print ("enter a integer for n ")
    n=io.read("*number")
    if  (n<0)   then return 1
    end
    sum = 0
    i = 0
    while (i<=n) do
    print = (sum + i^2) end
```

Comment: you don't incriment i, and you must do smth like this in your loop
`sum = sum + i^2`

Comment: the program must print the sum ... ok , i deleted "print = (sum + i^2)" and wrote : sum = sum + i^2 ... what to do with "i"?

Comment: code like this `print ("enter a integer for n ")
n=io.read("*number")
if  (n<0)   then return 1
end
sum = 0
i = 0
while (i<=n) do
sum= (sum + i^2)
i = i + 1   end
print(sum)
`

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Now i get it why it didn't happen at the first place. 
Thank you , again.

Answer (score 0):

```
print ("enter a integer for n ")
n=io.read("*n") --not *number
if  (n<0)   then return 1 end

sum = 0
i = 1 --0 has no effect :)?
while (i<=n) do
    sum = sum + i^2
    i = i + 1
end

print(sum)
```